# Drop Down menu in wordpress theme

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I am using a free wordpress theme ,named Pitch [siteorigin.com/theme/pitch](http://siteorigin.com/theme/pitch) . I redesign the menu bar , so that the background of first element of the menu bar will show an image (the logo). To do so , I just add a simple block of code

```
ul#mainmenu-menu li.menu-item:first-child {
        background:url(images/logo.png) no-repeat ;
        text-indent:-9999px;
        width:200px;


        border:none;
        }
    ul#mainmenu-menu li.menu-item:first-child a:hover  {
        background:none;

    }
```

But the problem is , that image also appear in first element of the dropdown item too . Like the image 
http://i46.tinypic.com/oejcz.jpg

What did I do wrong , How can I fix this ?

Here is the complete CSS code http://pastebin.com/edsYrqWF

Comment: If you use ul#mainmenu-menu > li.menu-item:first-child it will only affect direct childs

Comment: How can I solve that ?

Answer (score 1):

Change your CSS like this :

```
ul#mainmenu-menu > li.menu-item:first-child {
    background:url(images/logo.png) no-repeat ;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    width:200px;
    border:none;
}
ul#mainmenu-menu > li.menu-item:first-child a:hover  {
    background:none;
}
```

It will only apply to your first menu level, not on sub-menus. Note the ">" in the CSS.

More informations here : http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching

Comment: @ShuvroShuvro You're welcome, you will now be able to mark this question as answered!